# File.read empty for a non empty file when testing with rspec

Tags: ruby, file, rspec

New to rubby and rspec i am trying to test a class that opens and write to a file.
The class name is SimpleLogger
Here is the spec that generates an error:

```
describe SimpleLogger do
  ...
  context 'when using a file' do
    require 'fakefs/spec_helpers'

    before(:all) do
      @path = 'my_file'
      logger = SimpleLogger.new @path
      logger.write "Hello, world!"
      logger.close
    end
    ...
    it 'we expect the file to have a valid content' do
      expect(File.read(@path)).to eq "Hello, world!\n"
    end
  end
end
```

The error generated is:

```
Failure/Error: expect(File.read(@path)).to eq "Hello, world!\n"

   expected: "Hello, world!\n"
        got: ""

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1 @@
   -Hello, world!
```

The file exists on my file system, and when I'm testing a simple `puts Find.read("my_file")` on an independant ruby file i've got the expected result.
I've tested and have the same issue without the `fakefs gem`

Why is it when run in a spec it doesn't work?
And beside that i fail to understand the advantage of fakefs, as it creates the file juste the same. So why fakefs is used?
And as it creates the file should i erase it within the spec?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I think you're going to have to share your `SimpleLogger` class to get help on this.

Comment: Will do as soon as i'm home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs/blob/master/lib/fakefs/spec_helpers.rb) - it seems that you need to include the helpers to activate the `FakeFS`:

> `FakeFS::SpecHelpers` provides a simple macro for RSpec example groups to turn FakeFS on and off.
>   To use it simply require 'fakefs/spec_helpers', then include FakeFS::SpecHelpers into any
>   example groups that you wish to use FakeFS in. For example:
>
> ```ruby
> require 'fakefs/spec_helpers'
>
> describe "Some specs that deal with files" do
>   include FakeFS::SpecHelpers
>   ...
> end
> ```
>
> By default, including FakeFS::SpecHelpers will run for each example inside a describe block.
>   If you want to turn on FakeFS one time only for all your examples, you will need to
>   include FakeFS::SpecHelpers::All.
>
> Alternatively, you can include FakeFS::SpecHelpers in all your example groups using RSpec's
>   configuration block in your spec helper:
>
> ```ruby
> require 'fakefs/spec_helpers'
>
> Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
>   config.include FakeFS::SpecHelpers
> end
> ```
>
> If you do the above then use_fakefs will be available in all of your example groups.

You will also need to use `before(:each)` instead of `before(:all)` - like many unit test helpers, `FakeFS` adheres to unit-test isolation principles, in which side-effects of one test should not affect another's. That is why after every test, the gem 'resets' the state of its container, and clears all files from it.

Comment: That dit it putting the `include FakeFS::SpecHelpers` and using `:each`in the before statement. Thanks a lot ;). But i don't get it why it didn't work before. FakeFS needs a new fake file for each test? Since the first test only checks for file existence I do not understand why the `:each`is necessary?

Comment: thanks a lot ;) can't yed add the +1 for your answer but will do once my reputation allows it ;)